Upgrading IdentityModel from 4.0.0 to 5.x breaks IsAuthenticated
5.x is the oldest version of IdentityModel that does not have dependency on Newtonsoft so I selected this version but its same outcome with 7.0.0
After upgrading I cant authenticate anymore, this line breaks in our custom middleware
if (!context.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated) throw new AuthenticationException();

can we have a minimal sample for this exception?

It was a bit hard to google this. But I found the solution IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation is deprecated. Moved over to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
